# Filter list with different list in it

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, functional-style

I have a list like:

```
   {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, 
    {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3},  {4,15},      {{4, 16}, 2},{4,18}}
```

Now I want to filter this list. First I want to delete lists that have the form: 
`{a,b}` like `{4,15}` and `{4,18}`. So what remains is:

```
 {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, 
  {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14} ,3}, {{4, 16}, 2}}
```

And now I want only the lists which are a minimum:
For example now you have a list with:

```
{{4, 14}, 1} and {{4, 14}, 3}
{{4, 16}, 1} and {{4, 16}, 2}
```

I want that only `{{4, 14}, 1}` and `{{4, 16}, 1}` remain (minimum of the third number).

Finally remains:

```
{{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}
```

How can I easily do this??

Comment: Glenn, as you can see from the answers below there is ambiguity in your question.  Do you want to return only elements of the form `{{_, _}, min}` where `min` is the *global* minimum across all lists, or rather elements where `min` is the smallest value *within the set* that share a common first part (e.g. `{4, 14}`)?

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way using `Select` and `GatherBy`:

```
list = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 
    1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}};
x1 = Select[list, Length[#[[1]]] == 2 &];
x2 = GatherBy[x1, First];
(Sort[#] & /@ x2)[[All, 1]]
```

> {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}}

Comment: You could use `SortBy[#,Last]` instead of `Sort[#, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &] `. Or, for this problem, just `Sort` since the first elements are all the same

Comment: @SimonWoods You're right, updated.

Answer (score 4):

another way

```
list = DeleteCases[list, {x_Integer, y_Integer}];
min = Min[list[[All, 2]]];
Extract[list, Position[list[[All, 2]], min] ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You're assuming the minimum (third number) is just going to be one number, in this case 1, but it seems the different lists could have various minimum numbers.

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1},
       {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}}

First /@ Sort /@ GatherBy[Cases[lst, {_List, _}], First]
```

> ```
> {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}}
> ```

Or with ~infix~:

```
First /@ Sort /@ lst ~Cases~ {_List, _} ~GatherBy~ First
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple way of doing it:-

```
x = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1},
     {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}};
x2 = Replace[x, {a_Integer, b_Integer} -> Null, {1}];
x3 = DeleteCases[x2, Null];
types = Union[x3[[All, 1]]];
First[Sort[Cases[x3, {#, _}]]] & /@ types
```

> {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}}

Answer (score 2):

An approach based on Cases:

```
lst = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1},
   {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}}

Cases[list, {{_, _}, Min[list /. {{_, _}, x_} -> x]}]
```

> {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

With

```
x = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, 
  {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}};
x2 = {{{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, 
  {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}, {{4, 14}, 2}};
```

you can also use

```
 Union[Cases[x, {{ _, _ }, _}], SameTest -> (First@#1 == First@#2 &)]
```

or

```
 (* if the elements `{{a,b}, c}` are already sorted with respect to the the last entry:*)
 DeleteDuplicates[Cases[x, {{_, _}, _}], (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)] 
 (* if not: *)
 DeleteDuplicates[SortBy[#, Last] &@Cases[x, {{_, _}, _}], (#1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &)]
```

to get:

```
(* {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}} *)
```

Update: Further alternatives that preserve the ordering of the input list:

```
cleanUp2[x_] :=  With[{gthrd = GatherBy[Select[x, Depth[#] == 3 &], First]},
   Join @@ Pick[#, Last /@ #, Min @@ (Last /@ #)] & /@ gthrd];
cleanUp3[x_] := DeleteCases[x, Alternatives[{_Integer, _},
    {w : {_, _}, z_} /; z > Min @@ Last /@ Cases[x, {w, _}]]]; 
cleanUp4[x_] :=  Cases[x, {w : {_, _}, z_} /; z == Min @@ Last /@ Cases[x, {w, _}]];
```

Example:

```
 cleanUp3[x2]
 (* {{{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 2}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Using `MinimalBy`:**

```
list = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 
   1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}};

DeleteCases[list, {_?AtomQ, _?AtomQ}, {1}] // MinimalBy[Last]
```

> {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy` and `Select`:

```
lst = {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1},
       {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}, {{4, 14}, 3}, {4, 15}, {{4, 16}, 2}, {4, 18}};

First@GroupBy[Select[lst, Length[Flatten@#] > 2 &], Last, Sort]

(* {{{4, 14}, 1}, {{4, 15}, 1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 17}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 1}} *)
```

**Edit**: By @Syed's suggestion, another way:

```
Cases[list, {{__}, _}] // GroupBy[#, Min@Last][1] & (*Thanks, mate!*)
```

Comment: Try: ` Cases[list, {{__}, _}] // GroupBy[#, Min@Last][1] &`